# Missing input output annotations gradle 7.3 issue with java 17

Tags: java, docker, gradle

I have upgraded to **Gradle 7.3** to make it compatiple with **Java17**.I keep getting the below error for task buildDocker

Task :buildDocker FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Some problems were found with the configuration of task ':buildDocker' (type 'DockerTask').

  - In plugin 'docker' type 'se.transmode.gradle.plugins.docker.DockerTask' property 'apiEmail' is missing an input or output annotation.

    Reason: A property without annotation isn't considered during up-to-date checking.

    Possible solutions:

    1. Add an input or output annotation.
    2. Mark it as @Internal.

    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.3/userguide/validation_problems.html#missing_annotation for more details about this problem.
  - In plugin 'docker' type 'se.transmode.gradle.plugins.docker.DockerTask' property 'apiPassword' is missing an input or output annotation.

    Reason: A property without annotation isn't considered during up-to-date checking.

    Possible solutions:

    1. Add an input or output annotation.
    2. Mark it as @Internal.

    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.3/userguide/validation_problems.html#missing_annotation for more details about this problem.
  - In plugin 'docker' type 'se.transmode.gradle.plugins.docker.DockerTask' property 'apiUsername' is missing an input or output annotation.

    Reason: A property without annotation isn't considered during up-to-date checking.

    Possible solutions:

    1. Add an input or output annotation.
    2. Mark it as @Internal.

    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.3/userguide/validation_problems.html#missing_annotation for more details about this problem.
  - In plugin 'docker' type 'se.transmode.gradle.plugins.docker.DockerTask' property 'applicationName' is missing an input or output annotation.

    Reason: A property without annotation isn't considered during up-to-date checking.

    Possible solutions:

    1. Add an input or output annotation.
    2. Mark it as @Internal.

    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.3/userguide/validation_problems.html#missing_annotation for more details about this problem.
  - In plugin 'docker' type 'se.transmode.gradle.plugins.docker.DockerTask' property 'baseImage' is missing an input or output annotation.

    Reason: A property without annotation isn't considered during up-to-date checking.

    Possible solutions:

    1. Add an input or output annotation.
    2. Mark it as @Internal.

    The task written is build.gradle is

    task buildDocker(type: Docker, dependsOn: build) {
    applicationName = 'api'
    dockerfile = file('src/docker/Dockerfile')
    doFirst {
    copy {
    from file('src/docker')
    from war
    into stageDir
    }
    }
    }

Comment: IMHO that means that you should switch to a different plugin for creating docker images. The problem has been reported to the plugin authors (https://github.com/Transmode/gradle-docker/issues/160) 9 months ago but the plugin was never updated to make it compatible with Gradle 7.

Answer (score 2):

There is no fix for this issue yet from the transmode team, the plugin was last updated 6years ago, and the last official release by them was 1.2.

Please see the below article in gradle forum, where they suggest to look for an alternative.
https://discuss.gradle.org/t/missing-an-input-or-output-annotation/41061